# Django: Does filepicker.io use passthrough or direct approach?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, filepicker.io

After reading this [article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) on heroku, I've decided that I want to use a direct upload approach with my django project to allow users to upload files directly to my amazon s3 bucket.

According to their docs, [filepicker.io](http://filepicker.io) (along with the [django-filepicker](https://github.com/Ink/django-filepicker) plugin) seems to integrate well with amazon s3, but it is unclear whether or not filepicker.io uses a direct upload approach or pass-through approach.

Which does filepicker.io use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their home page.

> Your files are stored in your existing S3 bucket. We handle all the complicated javascript and backend APIs to give you a clean and elegant way of saving files directly to your S3 bucket.

Since they fallback to Iframe embedding, It's likely that the "upload" will go through their server before ending up in your bucket. But that's bandwidth that you don't have to pay for.

Comment: It does indeed use passthrough. It gives more flexibility in terms of being able to do resilient uploads via chunks (s3 has a minimum chunk size that is often too large) as well as browser compatibility with flash and iframe fallbacks.